# How to solve integral of formula consisting of derivative of the delta function.

Tags: dirac-delta

The question is
$$
\int ^4 _{-4} (t-2)^2\delta'\left(-\frac13t+\frac12\right)dt
$$

---

The solution of the text book is

\begin{align}
\int ^4 _{-4} (t-2)^2\delta'\left(-\frac13t+\frac12\right)dt
&=\int ^4 _{-4} 3(t-2)^2\delta'\left(t-\frac32\right)dt \\
&=\int ^4 _{-4} \left[{\frac34\delta'\left(t-\frac32\right)+3\delta\left(t-\frac32\right)}\right]dt\\
&=3
\end{align}

---

My solution is
\begin{align*}
\int ^4 _{-4} (t-2)^2\delta'\left(-\frac13t+\frac12\right)dt
&=3\int ^4 _{-4} (t-2)^2\delta'\left(t-\frac32\right)dt \\
&=-3\int ^4 _{-4} \left[{\frac{d}{dt}(t-2)^2}\right]_\frac32 \delta\left(t-\frac32\right)dt\\
&=-3\cdot2\cdot\left(\frac32-2\right)\int ^4 _{-4}\delta\left(t-\frac32\right)dt\\
&=3\cdot1\\ &=3
\end{align*}

---

My solution is used the following equation derived by parts.

$if\ \ \ t_1 < t_0 < t_1,$
$$
\int ^{t_2} _{t_1} x(t) \delta ^ {(n)} (t-t_0) dt
= (-1)^{(n)} \int ^{t_2} _{t_1} x^{(n)}(t) \delta(t-t_0) dt = (-1)^{(n)}x^{(n)} (t_0)\\
$$

---

The result is same as $3$. However, I cannot understand the textbook's solution.

Can someone explain how the first line became the second line in textbook's solution?

Comment: Note that $\delta'(ax)=\frac1{a\,|a|}\delta'(x)$

Comment: Your mistake is in the first line since $$\delta'\left(-\frac13x\right)\ne3\delta'\left(x\right).$$

Comment: Thank you. I understood what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither seems correct:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-4}^4(t-2)^2\delta'\left(-\frac13t+\frac12\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
&=-3\int_{-4}^4(t-2)^2\,\mathrm{d}\delta\left(-\frac13t+\frac12\right)\\
&=3\int_{-4}^42(t-2)\delta\left(-\frac13t+\frac12\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=9\int_{-4}^42(t-2)\cdot\frac13\delta\left(-\frac13t+\frac12\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=9\cdot2\left(\frac32-2\right)\\[6pt]
&=-9\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

---

I've also done some numerical tests with approximations of $\delta$ in Mathematica, and they support the computation above.

I used $\delta_n(x)=ne^{-\pi n^2x^2}$ and computed
$$
\int_{-4}^4(x-2)^2\delta_n'\!\left(-\tfrac13x+\tfrac12\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
Using

`d[x_,n_] := n Exp[-Pi n^2x^2]`
`d1[x_,n_] := Evaluate[D[d[x,n],x]]`
`NIntegrate[(t-2)^2 d1[-t/3+1/2,100],{t,-4,4},WorkingPrecision->20,MaxRecursion->100]`

for $n=100$, Mathematica 8 gives $-9.0000000000000000000$.

Comment: Thank you, can I ask one more? Is $\delta(at)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(t)$ wrong?

Comment: No. In fact I used that fact to get from the third line to the fourth.

Comment: I followed your process. I can't find any wrong points. However, I cannot find wrong points in my process. Oh my god..